# Button doesn't work if I use template literals to toggle CSS classes in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

I have a CSS module called styles and this React code. It's a div with two buttons inside. I use the isMenuActive state to verify if the menu is active or not. If it is active, the CSS class 'active' gets in and the menu appears, otherwise not.

```
  <div className={`${styles.customerOptionsMenu} ${isMenuActive ? styles.active : null}`}>
    <button onClick={() => { console.log('hi') }}>
      <span className="material-icons">edit</span>Editar
    </button>
    <button onClick={() => {console.log('hi')}}>
      <span className="material-icons">delete</span>Deletar
    </button>
  </div>
```

When I click the buttons, nothing happens.

But If I store the button as a global variable in developer tools and run button.click() it works fine if I remove the template literals:

```
  <div className={styles.customerOptionsMenu + styles.active}>
    <button onClick={() => { console.log('hi') }}>
      <span className="material-icons">edit</span>Editar
    </button>
    <button onClick={() => {console.log('hi')}}>
      <span className="material-icons">delete</span>Deletar
    </button>
  </div>
```

It works fine.

Why??? And what should I do to keep changing the classes when isMenuActive changes?

Edit: Full code with the button that changes isMenuActive

```
  const [isMenuActive, setIsMenuActive] = useState(false)
  const onBlur = () => { setIsMenuActive(!isMenuActive)}

  return(
    <td>
      <button onBlur={onBlur} className={styles.customerOptions} onClick={() => setIsMenuActive(!isMenuActive)}>
        <span className="material-icons">more_horiz</span>
      </button>
      <div className={`${styles.customerOptionsMenu} ${isMenuActive ? styles.active : null}`}>
        <button onClick={() => { console.log('hi') }}>
          <span className="material-icons">edit</span>Editar
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => {console.log('hi')}}>
          <span className="material-icons">delete</span>Deletar
        </button>
      </div>
    </td>
  )
```

New edit: The answer is in the comments by Pandaiolo. The problem was the onBlur={onBlur} code, when I removed it from the button everything worked fine!

Comment: Hi! What code changes `isMenuActive` value? You say you trigger a `click` event on a button, but probably not the buttons you share above? As they only do `console.log`?

Comment: Hi Pandaiolo, thanks for the answer! I will edit the question including the full code with the code that changes isMenuActive!

Comment: I think the space is fine in your template literal, because it references two different class names. But maybe the `onBlur` is called after the click? 1. click 2. button becomes focus 3. button blurs ? Not sure. But in that case it would toggle the state two times, cancelling its effect. Maybe try with just the `onClick` and without the `onBlur` at first?  And you can add a `console.log('isMenuActive`, isMenuActive)` before the return statement to see it's value along rerenders, see if it matches what you expect.

Comment: Hey!!! It works!!! Indeed it was the onBlur! Thank you so much Pandaiolo!! I was trying to fix it almost the whole afternoon.

Comment: Ok I'll put this as an answer then ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the space is fine in your template literal, because it references two different class names. You probably want to use `${isMenuActive ? styles.active :''}` otherwise `null` becomes the *string* `"null"`, which is probably harmless unless you have a class `.null` that applies some styles, but that is basically not what you want.

But maybe the onBlur is called after the click?

1. click
2. button becomes focus
3. button blurs ?

Not sure. But in that case it would toggle the state two times, cancelling its effect. Maybe try with just the `onClick` and without the `onBlur` at first?

And you can add a `console.log('isMenuActive', isMenuActive)` before the return statement to see it's value along rerenders, see if it matches what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

To handle changing classnames you can use the [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) package to do something like this:

```
import cx from "classnames";

<div className={cx(styles.customerOptionsMenu, { styles["active"]: isMenuActive })}>
    <button onClick={() => { console.log('hi') }}>
      <span className="material-icons">edit</span>Editar
    </button>
    <button onClick={() => {console.log('hi')}}>
      <span className="material-icons">delete</span>Deletar
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Katie, thank you so much for the answer! Unfortunatly, I tried to remove the space but the behavior remains the same. This is such a mysterious thing. But I will definitely look into classnames package. Thanks!!

Comment: I tried classnames but it returns an error: Type 'false' cannot be used as an index type.  TS2538. The part of the code "isMenuActive && "active" appears underlined with red, indicating the error location. I will try to fix it!

Comment: Hi @LeoHolanda I just updated my answer to include a better solution, and removed the string stuff per Pandaiolo's answer. This iteration utilizes `classnames` to set the active styles when isMenuActive === true. It will not render the active classname if isMenuActive === false. This moves the burden away from what you're retrieving from styles and lets classnames handle the logic.

Comment: Hey, this is great! I'm planning to expand the styles so using classnames to handle the logic will be of great help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The isMenuActive is not defined. Place it in as a parameter as so:

```
export default function App(isMenuActive) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
  <div className={`${styles.customerOptionsMenu} ${isMenuActive ? styles.active : null}`}>
    <button onClick={() => { console.log('hi') }}>
      <span className="material-icons">edit</span>Editar
    </button>
    <button onClick={() => {console.log('hi')}}>
      <span className="material-icons">delete</span>Deletar
    </button>
  </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey man! Thanks for the answer! I didn't include the code about isMenuActive but now I edited the code and included it. Sorry!